# VSTO Excel ribbon tab - separate code (.NET) into modules

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, code-structure

I'm on the VBA ---> VB .NET journey and am in the process of building a custom Excel ribbon for Excel 2013/16 in Visual Studio.

When I selected the ribbon as the project, Visual Studio added a few tabs, one of which houses the code for the on-click actions for the buttons.

My background being VBA, I'm used to being able to have separate modules for different things and want to do the same (e.g. one module for calculation buttons, one module for formatting buttons, etc.) but can't see a way to have separate modules in this fashion. I tried to just create a new tab in VS but got nowhere with that...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Project>Add new Module 
by this way you can create separate module for all different calculation.
you can call this module procedure from button click event of ribbon code.

Comment: consider adding more information in your answer for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Since you are now using VS Studoi for Excel Plugin (VSTO) development, I don't think here you will find different modules for differet functions/onclick/events.

But as an alternate you can crearte partial classes here and can break your code in different files. In vb.net it will add new functions and event code in the single file only by default

Comment: Hi! Sorry I had to park the project for a bit but back on it now. Thank you for your response.
Could you elaborate a little further - I tried to do this today without much success.
What I'm trying to avoid is having a single class with 1000 lines of code in it so if you have any advice on how to structure it (and the steps required to set that up), that would be very helpful!